# How to communicate between a GUI and a microservice module in a monolithic application?

Tags: java, asynchronous, ipc, microservices, synchronous

I've got a legacy monolith application that I have to redesign. Unfortunately, the mandate is to redesign in bite-sized approaches.

At the moment, I need to implement a new public facing web-service for a particular module. I'm taking advantage of the situation to split it off into its own service.  However, I am stuck with an issue. The server generated GUI (struts monolith) needs some data from my microservice. The obvious answer is to provide a REST interface (JSON/Protocol Buffers, etc) in the web service for my monolith to consume in order to provide results to the user. But is this my only choice?

Ideally, I would like to move to asynchronous communications between the monolith and the service, but what do I do when a user needs specific data from the microservice? How can one do that in an asynchronous process?  With the user waiting on the GUI (a synchronous event), how can I have the communication protocol between the GUI and the webservice not be synchronous as well?

In this particular instance, the user will use the microservice to upload data in bulk (csv file). The microservice will process the data and provide options to the user to manipulate the data once ready (all via API calls).  The business wants an option in the GUI to view/download the uploaded file. Essentially, the monolith (responsible for the GUI) needs to request the file from the service and return it to the user.

Is there any way to structure this design without using a synchronous IPC between the monolith and the microservice?

Comment: Too many questions at the same time... First you need to define for your-self a scope of microservice. As you said "user will use the microservice to upload data" then "microservice will process the data and provide options to the user to manipulate the data". Is it really microservice ? or is it usual SOA design? ... upload, process, provide options, manipulate...

Comment: Sync vs. Async is a different story, not necessary related to microservice conception.

Comment: and... "Essentially, the monolith needs to request the file from the service and return it to the user"  - can it be another microservice? one uploads file, another returns it?

Comment: @Vadim You are right that it isn't truly a microservice in the definition of a microservice.  It is more of a "meta-microservice".  If I were to truly split it up into a handful of micro-services, right now, it would never pass an architecture review as the organization is extremely conservative in their approach.  However, I wanted to take a first step in that direction.  I guess you could say it is more of classical SOA design, with a longer term vision towards micro-service implementations

Comment: Understood :) I have pretty much similar troubles. :) "Microservice" is a ver "sexy" word now, but when it comes to reality... :(

Comment: But I'm in better position - we have a classical SOA already in place and for now I'm going to separate and regroup services into independent deployable units (i.e. EAR files) to be able later make them a real microservices with containers etc. My first focus is a maximal independence for each of them. IMHO: yes microservice can have multiple operations in it if they fall into one "functional domain" (like file operations) and can be independent from other services... good luck... for both of us:)

Comment: @Vadim That's essentially my plan - trying to regroup functionality in independent deployable units, but I need to understand how to make the units talk to each other.  What is your plan?  How will the different EARs communicate between themselves?

Comment: My plan is to make them not to "talk to each other", but package all needed pieces in each "microservice". Let say two functionalities A and B both require common functionality C. Standard SOA makes three services A, Service B and Service C. Then A talks to C and B talks to C. More important all three are separate deployment units. So, there are only three instances running.

Comment: Now let's do it flat or straight... Make only two deployment units instead of three. EAR 1 contains service A and service C and EAR 2 has service B and service C. So, each of upfront services has it's own running instance of service C. Then Service C now is not a bottle neck for both services. they are autonomous. For the beginning they can be deployed to one J2EE container as separate EAR, and when containerized environment will be ready there is nothing to change to deploy them in separate containers. That is my vision of difference between classic SOA and Microservices,

Comment: IMHO: Just because microservice conception born not from classic SOA, but from J2EE monolith apps with UI people very often start think about "one microservice talk to another". That is why I told about "scope of microservice"... Sure, from logical and functional prospective there could be different components (i.e. service A, B, C), but from system topology there are only two microservices (A-C and B-C). Microservice vs. classic SOA.

Comment: A,B ,C may be different projects from development prospective, but they are not individual deployable units. Microservices are, and can be kind of "lego" constructions from components bricks.

Comment: @Vadim I get your viewpoint; I agree with it too, to a certain degree.  However, at some point, no matter how you design an app, A-C will need to communicate with B-C in some form more than just async messaging.  Unless your A-C has its own interface (GUI, Rest, etc) and B-C has its own interface as well.  I'm stuck here with my interface on A-C and not yet developed one for B-C.  So B-C needs to provide data to A-C until it gets its own GUI developed.

Comment: GUI is another story. For me it is not needed I'm working on middleware services, service bus etc. But... That is a main point of microservices - move GUI as much as possible to the client (mostly in JavaScript frameworks) and communicate with microservices only for data (mostly through REST, because XML is not good for JavaScript). if GUI on client is not possible make a UI tier, which will communicate with microservices A-C and B-C separatelly. There is nothing bad with that. But if functionality requires A to use B, then microservice must be A-B-C (may A-C and B-C be there too if needed).